# Transit visa needed or not for Delhi Airport?

Tags: visas, transit, del

I will be travelling through Delhi International airport. My flight lands at 1 am in Delhi and my next flight is 10 am of the same day to Kathmandu, Nepal.

Do I need a visa to collect my luggage and check in again to catch the flight to Nepal?

I will be checking out my baggage and checking in again while flying back from Nepal to Delhi in order to catch a flight to Europe.

In that case do I need the transit visa and if yes will the same visa work  both times?

I even read some post related to same issue, some were suggesting that if I inform the airlines they will transfer my luggage to my connecting flight. And I do not have to get of the custom.

Is it always true or do I have to apply for the transit visa?

Comment: i bought the ticket from Europe to Delhi from travel agent and bought separate ticket online to kathmandu from Delhi.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: Which airlines?

Comment: Do you really have to collect your luggage in Delhi?

Answer (score 1):

You are not in transit; you have two point-to-point journeys.

The first is Europe to Delhi - in this scenario your status is the same as someone traveling to Delhi as their final destination - this is, you need authorization to enter India. In fact, the airline will refuse to issue you a boarding pass if you cannot show valid documentation that allows you entry into India; since your boarding pass and ticket are from Europe - Delhi.

The second is Delhi to Kathmandu -in this scenario you are just like anyone else traveling from Delhi to Kathmandu; you need the appropriate documents to exit India and enter Nepal.

To enter India, unless you hold an Indian passport - you will need a visa of some sort. The kind of visa you need will depend on the length of your stay.

If its between 24 and 72 hours, you need a transit visa. Anything more than that and you need a tourist visa.

However, as you are going through customs and collecting your bags - you'll need a visa of some sort even if your stay is less than 24 hours.

Now, as for the rules:

1. There is no transit visa on arrival. You'll need to arrange a transit visa in advance. There are two types - a single entry and a double entry.
2. If you are a citizen of Cambodia, Finland, Japan, Laos, Luxembourg, Myanmar, New Zealand, Philippines, Singapore, Indonesia or Vietnam you can get a **tourist visa** on arrival which is valid for a single entry.

> I even read some post related to same issue, some were suggesting that
>   if i inform the airlines they will transfer my luggage to my
>   connecting flight.

This depends entirely on the airlines involved and I would personally not rely on this being offered.

For more information, I suggest the following:

- [Delhi Airport Website](http://www.newdelhiairport.in/fi-know-the-rules.aspx)
- [Bureau of Immigration Website](http://boi.gov.in/content/apply-visa-online)
- [Online application website for Indian Visas](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/)